# Json decode with root property

Tags: php, json

I cant seem to figure out, or find any information to help me solve what should be a simple problem.. I have some php code, it using curl get request to talk to an api, and the responce im getting from the api is

```
{"styleHolder":[{"id":100000929,"makeId":200005143,"year":2001,"makeName":"Ford","makeNiceName":"ford","modelId":"Ford_F_150","ect.......
```

What I need is to take the id, and turn it into a php variable..

I know how to use something like:

```
$myArray = json_decode($resp);
$id = $myArray->id;
echo $id;
```

but because the responce has styleHolder as a root property, I cant seem to figure out how to parce out id.. Any help would be great!

Comment: `var_dump($myArray)` would tell you exactly what you have to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`styleHolder` is an array, so you need to first access the array element, then it's `id` property.

```
$myArray = json_decode($resp);
$id = $myArray->styleHolder[0]->id;
echo $id;
```

Comment: One more question? What about getting the value for usedTradeIn from this responce?  {"tmv":{"nationalBasePrice":{"baseMSRP":null,"baseInvoice":null,"deliveryCharges":null,"tmv":null,"usedTmvRetail":5462.0,"usedPrivateParty":4291.0,"usedTradeIn":3589.0,"

Comment: Try: `$obj->tmv->nationalBasePrice->usedTradeIn`